# Why do I get different results with same random seed, same computer, same program

Tags: python, random, seed

I am running a simulation with a lot of modules.
I use random a number of times.
I read input files.
I use rounding.
Of course, I am setting a random.seed(1) in the very first line of my program, immediately after importing random.

Even though, shouldn't I get exactly the same result running the same program same parameters in the same computer with the same input files?

Comment: The `random` module is not the only source of nondeterminism in your program. What else are you doing? Multithreading? Relying on dict iteration order?

Comment: Hmm... Yes, I have dictionaries. And I get minimum from lists which may have a lot of numbers that are equal.

Comment: The code has a lot of modules. The paper is under review. When accepted I will make all of it available.

Comment: but then, it is possible that everything is equal and I still get different results? very weird

Comment: Is it possible that getting minimum out of dictionaries give me a different number in different runs?

Comment: self.available_postings.sort(key=methodcaller('get_wage_base'), reverse=True)
            self.candidates.sort(key=attrgetter('qualification'), reverse=False)

Comment: both above are dictionaries

Comment: Have you tried running Python interpreter with fixed HASHSEED? Set [`PYTHONHASHSEED`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED) environment variable to arbitrary value before execution.

Comment: BTW. Sorting is guaranteed to be stable, so it won't influence your output. Still, without full source code it's rather a guessing game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inject the source for random numbers as a service into the modules using it. You can then easily replace it with a deterministic version that gives a predefined sequence of numbers. This is for example a prerequisite for proper unit testing and it also applies to things like the time, too.

Concerning your case, you could e.g. inject an instance of `random.Random` instead of using a global (the one provided by the `random` module). This generator could then be seeded appropriately (constructor argument) to provide reproducible sequences.

Bad code:

```
def simulation():
    sum = 0
    for i in range(10):
        sum += random.random()
    return sum / 10

# Think about how to test that code without
# monkey-patching random.random.
```

Good code:

```
def simulation(rn_provider):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(10):
        sum += rn_provider()
    return sum / 10

rng1 = random.Random(0)
sum1 = simulation(rng1.random)
rng2 = random.Random(0)
sum2 = simulation(rng2.random)
print(sum1 == sum2)
```

The code here uses a simple function parameter. For classes, you could also use "dependency injection".

BTW: Remember hearing that globals are bad? Here's your example why. ;)

Comment: Hmm. I understand. But I don't know how to apply it. You mean a random class, instantiated in my_random?

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that!

Comment: HI @ulrich-eckhardt, I replaced all my random choices (29 ocurrences)

Comment: Now, I have   '    fixed_seed = random.Random(1)' and used fixed_seed all over. But, still. Results are different

Comment: Well, maybe then it's time for you to show some code, so that others can reproduce it.

Comment: `fixed_seed = random.Random(1)`

Comment: others modules (agents, demographics, time iteration, generator...)

Comment: `from parameters import fixed_seed`

Comment: examples of use `money = fixed_seed.randrange(20, 200)`

Comment: `family = fixed_seed.choice(families)`

Comment: ` if fixed_seed.random() < probability_urban:`
       `urban = True`

Comment: and so on... I have 20 modules and 29 times I use the `fixed_seed` instance

Comment: Would it make any difference if it were a function

Comment: I `import random` in all modules I need. Should that be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Hmmm. I erased all `import random`, keeping just one. Still, results are different...

Comment: FINALLY! There was another source of randomness: `round(noncentral_chisquare(4, 5))` I changed it for `random.uniform()` But I don't want a uniform distribution... I'll test some distributions from random. Thanks y'all

Comment: You got this completely wrong. Instead of adding confused comments, extract a minimal example, as the site guidelines here require. Firstly, that helps you understand the problem and secondly, the site guidelines here require it.

Comment: Sorry. I understand. But copying 20 modules each with 100-200 lines makes no sense. Also, your answer helped me develop the reasoning and come to the right solution.

Comment: Last time: Study the posting guidelines! You don't have to copy a bunch of modules, just **extract** a **minimal** but **complete** example.