# python random number why isn't it same on all computers

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, pip

One friend that I don't have any communication with anymore once told me the following:

> Using that library(python's random) you can select a seed If you give it at seed it
> means the randomly generated number will always be the same No matter
> what computer you run it on

So I tried to test this, because this is what I need so it's the same on all computers and everytime someone calls this(this is important, as I am working on a blockchain NFT and trust is important here)

So I found this: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-generate-random-numbers-in-python/

on that link, there's example:

```
from random import seed
from random import random
# seed random number generator
seed(1)
# generate some random numbers
print(random(), random(), random())
# reset the seed
seed(1)
# generate some random numbers
print(random(), random(), random())
```

running above in playground of python, I get

> (0.417022004703, 0.720324493442, 0.000114374817345) (0.417022004703,
> 0.720324493442, 0.000114374817345)

But as you can see, on that website, the creator of that post got the following:

> 0.13436424411240122 0.8474337369372327 0.763774618976614
> 0.13436424411240122 0.8474337369372327 0.763774618976614

Why aren't they same on all computers then ? I am using the same seed. and how can I ensure that they will be the same ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#notes-on-reproducibility

Comment: Different versions of Python? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231087/why-do-i-get-different-results-with-same-random-seed-same-computer-same-progra

Comment: You should use Python 3.

Comment: What's that "playground of python"?

Comment: That can happen when the [mapping from the seed value to the actual internal state of the generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48505649/2166798) varies across the versions on the different machines.  A more reliable alternative would be to use getstate/setstate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ANSWER is that, even though you have tagged Python-3.x, you are actually using Python 2, and the random number algorithm changed between 2 and 3.

I can tell that because your `print` statement printed the values as a tuple, with parentheses.  That wouldn't happen with Python 3's print function.

It's odd to rely on a particular implementation of a random number algorithm for financial purposes.  If you really need reproducibility, then you should embed your own algorithm.  There are several RNGs that are not difficult to code.  But if the algorithm needs to be predictable, why not just use incrementing numbers?  If you don't need randomness, then don't use randomness.

Comment: Then why do I get the same numbers both in Python 2 and Python 3, even in 3.10?

Comment: The algorithm hasn’t changed, it’s still MT19937.  The mapping from seed to state has changed.

Comment: @pjs When did that happen, and can you share a link where I can read about that?

Comment: @KellyBundy The link is in the first comment in response to the question.  I don’t know precisely when it happened, but the solution is to use getstate/setstate which is portable across MT19937 for all languages and language versions.

Comment: @pjs Doesn't that say the opposite? That it "will continue to produce the same sequence when [...] given the same seed"?

Comment: @KellyBundy No, it means you have to use the old mapping algorithm, i.e., the “compatible seeder”.

Comment: @pjs That's not what it says.

Comment: @pjs I get the same `(0.13436424411240122, 0.84743373693723267, 0.76377461897661403)` with Python 2.3.0 from 18 years ago as well as with Python 3.10. And 2.3.0 is when it started using Mersenne Twister. So I'm now quite confident I'm not the one reading that incorrectly.

Comment: OK, so the real issue here is actually with the programming-hero.com "Python Playground".  That is some bastardized version of Python 2.  It has a 2010 copyright, but the `sys` module doesn't even have a `version` string.  He must be doing is own random thing.

Comment: @TimRoberts Good job finding that, I had tried but failed :-). I also asked the OP but they didn't care :-(

Comment: @KellyBundy As I said above, MT19937 is the same algorithm across languages and language versions. That said, the mapping of seed values to the full 19937 bit state space is not defined as part of the MT19937 spec, and that *does* change between languages and versions. If you have access to v2 and v3 implementations using the same mapping, you'll get the same results. If not, the getstate/setstate pair of functions remains the most reliable way to guarantee portability. The fact that you got identical output based on seeding is no guarantee others will.

Comment: @pjs Doesn't need to be part of the MT19937 spec if the consistency is guaranteed by Python as it is.

Comment: @KellyBundy From the [notes on reproducibility](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#notes-on-reproducibility): "The generator’s random() method will continue to produce the same sequence **when the compatible seeder** is given the same seed." That means reproducibility isn't guaranteed unless you take steps to assure it by being aware of and using the `version` argument of `seed`. Just calling `seed(1)` as OP did is not sufficient to guarantee reproducibility.

Comment: @TimRoberts Found some [infos](https://trinket.io/faq#what-version-of-python-do-you-use).

Comment: @pjs Sounds like [both versions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed) are equivalent for ints, though. And I do get the [same values](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5UoFKempnBhEYfwuLhA8hqGOgqGmlwFRZl5JRoQCQ1NHQVMliZCvREp6tXT8vOTEovUSbQGoY042/7/BwA) with both versions when using seed `1` (but different values when using a string).

Comment: @TimRoberts `print(random.random)` prints `<function <native JS>>`. Uh...

Comment: "But if the algorithm needs to be predictable, why not just use incrementing numbers?" Many algorithms use "random" values as part of their process. They tend to be called "stochastic" rather than random. An example is stochastic gradient descent... which is quite commonly used in machine learning. The value of reproducible analysis is broadly accepted in the scientific community, hence the need for "predictable randomness".

Answer (score 2):

I get the post author's values both in Python 2.3.0 (over 18 years old) and in Python 3.10 (the newest, just a month old).

I get *your* values if I use `numpy.random` instead of Python's `random`.

So I suspect you're not telling the truth about your code or that that *"playground of python"* you're using is weird.

Comment: It is definitely the latter.  Good spotting.

Comment: @TimRoberts I btw found this by googling their number 0.417022004703, turns out they're not the first to call `random()` after `seed(1)` :-). Still not sure what that playground does, maybe it does use an even more ancient Python version that does also produce these numbers. Might try later...

Comment: @AttRigh As far as I'm aware, `random.random` **is** "machine invariant" (except possibly for differences in the  `float` type, but 1) that's [extremely unlikely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70189136/12671057) and 2) if you do have machines with differing `float` type, then you somewhat have no chance). Note that the OP of this question only got different results because they used a **broken/modified** Python installation. And if you take such broken installations into considerations, you can't guarantee *anything*.

Comment: @KellyBundy Thanks, good to know. Looking at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#notes-on-reproducibility) we have "If a new seeding method is added, then a backward compatible seeder will be offered. The generator’s random() method will continue to produce the same sequence when the compatible seeder is given the same seed." So I guess if I hard-code the seeder there version is guaranteed. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11929775/1892584) says that you can do this with `random.seed(s, version=1)`.

Comment: @KellyBundy I deleted my earlier comments because they were distracting for a reading.

Comment: @AttRigh It's not quite clear what they mean with "seeder" and "seeding method", those terms are only used in that section, and I don't see a definition anywhere on the whole page. I think they mean the mean the implementation of the `seed` method, and that "compatible seeder" is the part of the implementation that gets used when you use version=1 in current Python versions (theoretically, for example the next time they add a new way, instead of version=1/2/3 they could switch to crikey=42/666/'foo' or something even weirder, as long as they provide *some* way to get the old results). But...

Comment: ... realistically I do expect `version=1` to be future-safe.

Comment: @KellyBundy I agree that the documentation is unclear. I'm sorta reading between the lines based on the fact that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929701/why-is-seeding-the-random-generator-not-stable-between-versions-of-python/11929775#11929775) resolves a change in the randomization method between two versions of python3 by using the version argument. Though it's worth noting that in that answer's comment they say that random.shuffle() changed between implementations - the docs only say that random() will not change...